# Fixing object when camera open Unity AR

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

Im trying to create a AR Game in Unity for educational project.
I want to create something like pokemon go: when the camera open the object will be fixed somewhere on the real world and you will have to search for it with the camera.
My problem is that ARCore and vuforia groundDetection (I dont want to use targets) are only limited for few types of phone and i tried to use kudan sdk but it didnt work.
Any one can give me a tool or a tutorial on how to do this? I just need ideas or someone to tell me where to start?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why plane detection is limited to only some phones at this time is partially because older/less powerful phones cannot handle the required computing power.

If you want to make an app that has the largest reach, Vuforia is probably the way to go. Personally, I am not a fan of Vuforia, and I would suggest you use ARCore (and/or ARKit for iOS).

Since this is an educational tool and not a game, are you sure Unity is the way to go? I am sure you may be able to do it in Unity, but choosing the right platform for a project is important - just keep that in mind. You could make a native app instead.

If you want to work with ARCore and Unity (which is a great choice in general), [here is the first in a series of tutorials that can get you started as a total beginner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6YLbfO8gQ8).

Let me know if you have other questions :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I didnt choose unity, its required for this project (by my teacher). ARCore is limited so it's not an option right now. i need something that can work on all phones (at least smartphones that use android 5 and later versions ).

Comment: What did you decide on, and what are the requirements? Would appreciate any upvotes and marks as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPS data from phone to display object when the user arrived specific place you can show the object. You can search GPS based Augmented Reality on google. You can check this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6djed8e4n0